# Music synced with iTunes has a very low volume on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I noticed that recently when I sync my music from iTunes to the iPhone, the volume of the music is very very slow.

For example, I can barely hear it while biking on the street, or if I'm in noisy environment.

For sure some albums were louder than others, but I believe in the past it was much louder on average.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might have selected "Sound Check" (which will adjust your song volumes). Look at your iTunes preferences -> Playback to see if that is the case. Turning it off might help.

Comment: No, it is already disabled. I can't believe all songs have such a low volume

Answer (score 1):

You might have enabled a volume limit (Preferences>Music) which redefines what "maximum volume" means on the sliders, although it's very unlikely you would do that accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I went from having a iPhone 4s from July manufacturing with music on it that played back in my headphones as loud as it did from my iPad. Then my vibrate stoped working so I got it replaced at the apple store. Now I have a new iPhone 4s maufactured in 2013 and when I put all the music back on it, the sound level was really low compared to before.

Comment: Are you saying Agnew devices are not as loud, or that the asker needs to service their part. It's clear you are here to help move the discussion forward, but e direction isn't clear. Can you edit this, please?